# make visual studio editor not check ~ files

Tags: macos, visual-studio, emacs

I'm an Anaconda on Mac user and the newer versions of Anaconda are now downloading Microsoft's Visual Studio on the Mac. Pretty neat. Except that all of my files have been edited with EMACS and I have many `filename.py~` backup files, and VisualStudio is trying to check them all, and they don't check.

How do I configure VisualStudio so that it doesn't try to check the backup files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the backup files to go to a particular directory instead of $PWD.  I think the easiest way to do this is by installing `no-littering` (https://github.com/emacscollective/no-littering).  `no-littering` doesn't do anything to auto save files, but there is a note in its readme about how to put those in a common directory also.

---

If you don't want to install `no-littering`, do something like this:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "/path/to/backup/dir/")))
```